# Java - if/else fails immediately when supposed to pause

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I'm having troubles with a function in java. Here's my code:

```
    do{
        System.out.print("Proceed to payment? (y/n) ");
        input = scan.nextLine();
        if((input.trim()).equals("y")){
            break;
        }
        else if((input.trim()).equals("n")){
            System.out.print("Come back next time, " + name + ".");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid response. Try again.");
        }
    }
    while(true);
```

Basically, the first time the function loops it 'skips' the "input = scan.nextLine" and immediately prints "Invalid response. Try again." to the terminal. It then allows the user to input something, and works normally.

Yes, I have declared input, scan (java.util.Scanner;), and name earlier in my code. It'd be a great help if someone can point out what I've done wrong! Thanks!

Comment: Are you using scan again **before** this input?

Comment: Not in the same function, I do use it in earlier functions though

Comment: Ok, and is the one right before it scan.next()?

Comment: There is no other use of scan in that same function. In the function called before that one, there is a scan.nextInt(), but I don't know how that affects it.

Comment: Since scan is a class variable, it's still got parts of the `nextInt()` input, mainly the newline (or `Enter`) in the Scanner cache/buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably called `scan.next()`, or something like that, before entering the `do-while` loop. That left a next line character in the input, and the call to `scan.nextLine()` consumed it. To fix it, you could place a `scan.nextLine()` call right after `scan.next()` so it will consume the next line before entering the loop.

For example:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String input;
String name = scan.next();
scan.nextLine();
do {
    System.out.print("Proceed to payment? (y/n) ");
    input = scan.nextLine();
    // rest of the code
}
while(true);
```

Comment: @JasperSquire Glad to help! Ideally, if the `scan.nextInt()` call is in another method, you should place the `scan.nextLine()` call right after it instead of before the `do-while` loop. This will guarantee that any method you call after `scan.nextInt()` will have a clean input.

Answer (score 3):

While adding `scan.nextLine()` before does help, I keep a general rule of setting the delimiter whenever I initialize the Scanner class by using:

```
scan.useDelimiter("\n");
```

in this case, which uses a newline as a delimiter. As a result, for all the methods of scan, whenever the user presses `Enter`, it is interpreted as the end of the input. This includes, `nextInt()`, `nextDouble()`, `next()`etc...

Using the delimiter also means that I don't have to add `scan.nextLine()` after every non-`nextLine()` input.